# php array 2 dimension array into 1 dimension

Tags: php, arrays

hi everyone I want make new 1 array dimension from array 2 dimension and the code like this:

```
[0] => Array(
    [photo_data_id] => 0
    [photo_image] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37a.jpg
        )

    [photo_status] => 1
)

[1] => Array(
    [photo_data_id] => 1
    [photo_image] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6.jpg
            [1] => 6a.jpg
            [2] => 20141001_073231.jpg
        )

    [photo_status] => 1
 )
 [2] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 2
        [photo_image] => Array
            (
                [0] => 20.jpg
                [1] => 21.jpg
                [2] => 22.jpg
                [3] => 23.jpg
                [4] => 24.png
            )

        [photo_status] => 1
 )
```

and the result i want like below and than store into database:

```
[0] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 0
        [photo_image] => 37a.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)

[1] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 1
        [photo_image] => 6.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)
[2] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 1
        [photo_image] =>  6a.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)
[3] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 1
        [photo_image] => 20141001_073231.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)

[4] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 2
        [photo_image] => 20.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)

[5] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 2
        [photo_image] => 21.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)
[6] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 2
        [photo_image] =>  22.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)
[7] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 2
        [photo_image] => 23.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)
[8] => Array(
        [photo_data_id] => 2
        [photo_image] => 24.jpg
        [photo_status] => 1
)
```

please help me, i am a newbie, thank's before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array1 as $item) {
   foreach ($item['photo_image'] as $image) {
       $result[] = array(
           'photo_data_id' => $item['photo_data_id'],
           'photo_image' => $image,
           'photo_status' => $item['photo_status'],       
       );
   }
}

print_r($result);
```